# Incorrect Vector Pass output (No Alpha & Zero Values)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-passes

I am looking to render the vector pass in a OpenExr format with all channels. I have rendered on both 2.7 and 2.8 and the generated images have an empty alpha channel. The compositor is set as follows:

[image]

Two issues arise, the first is that the alpha channel is missing on every image as can seen by the recorded rgba values at the bottom of the window in the image below:

[image]

Also where a zero value would be expected, it seems to be set to RGBA(0.0039, 0.0039, 0.0039, 0). As seen below:

[image]

The same issues spans different versions and scenes, is there something wrong in my configuration or is this a bug? Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Did you make sure to disable the Motion Blur check box under the Cycles render properties panel? If not, the Vector Pass won't work properly

Also, for some reason, in order to save the Vector pass to OpenEXR with proper values, you first need to convert it from to RGBA then to Image format.

Something like this should work:

[image]

Also, to verify the values stored in the OpenEXR, just drag and drop the file into the compositor where you can also doublecheck them (that's what I did).

---

1. <s>Alpha channel is not used for the Vector Pass which uses XYZ components of each pixel vector stored as RGB only for the OpenEXR file.</s> *(see comment below)*
2. The non zero value could be attributed to movement of your camera, the background of the scene, rotation... or whatever image/color processing of the viewer used.

Comment: The Vector pass consists of two vectors according to https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html, one for (R) x and (G) y difference between current and previous frame and the second for the (B) x and (A) y  between the current and the next frame. And unfortunately the camera is static so it is not the source of the RGBA(0.0039, 0.0039, 0.0039, 0) value.

Comment: I stand corrected on point 1.

Comment: (also verified in code).